# Load data into a div when a select option is chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I have recently been playing around with jquery. I originally had three buttons with names of cities on and using the simple jquery .load function to enter the data into another separate div.

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".London").click(function(){
        $("#div1 h2").load("London.txt");
    });
    $(".NewYork").click(function(){
        $("#div1 h2").load("NewYork.txt");
    });
    $(".Shanghai").click(function(){
        $("#div1 h2").load("Shanghai.txt");
    });
});
</script>
```

I now want to change this and use a select box to do the same thing however when trying this it doesn't work.

```html
  <select class="Select">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select a City</option>
    <option value="NewYork" class="NewYork">New York</option>
    <option value="Shanghai" class="Shanghai">Shanghai</option>
    <option value="London" class="London">London</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Could you post the rest of your code (maybe the other `<div>`s you want to load stuff into?

Answer (score 2):

Use `change` event of `<select>` instead

```js
$(function() {
  var h2 = $('#div1').find('h2');
  $('.Select').on('change', function(e) {
    var city = $(this).val();
    h2.text('City changed to:' + city);
    var url = city + '.txt';
    h2.load(url, function(resp, status, req) {
      if ('error' === status) {
        h2.text('Failed to load url: ' + url);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="Select">
  <option value="" disabled='' selected=''>Select a City</option>
  <option value="NewYork">New York</option>
  <option value="Shanghai">Shanghai</option>
  <option value="London">London</option>
</select>
<div id="div1">
  <h2>Please select city from top</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use `change` event to of `select`. So try this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".Select").change(function(){
        if($(this).val() === "London") { //load London.txt } 
        else if($(this).val() === "NewYork") { //load NewYork.txt }
        else if($(this).val() === "Shanghai") { //load Shanghai.txt }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing with the selectors is wrong. `<option>` elements give their `value` attribute to the `<select>` when they are selected, so if you use

```
$(".Select").value
```

after you select an option, it will take the `value` of the selected option. Here's how I fixed your code:

```
$(".Select").on("change", function(){
    if ($(".Select").value == "London") {
        $("#div1 h2").load("London.txt");
    } else if ($(".Select").value == "NewYork") {
        $("#div1 h2").load("NewYork.txt");
    } else if ($(".Select").value == "Shanghai") {
        $("#div1 h2").load("Shanghai.txt");
    }
});
```